# How to set UINavigationControl nav bar title?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried almost everything on stack overflow, but to no avail. I've tried it all, but still nothing, so I'm here. I'm simply just trying to set the title to a white color and then set the title to "Terms of Service". Here's what I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TOCViewController : UINavigationController

@end
```

//

```
#import "TOCViewController.h"

@interface TOCViewController ()

@end

@implementation TOCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Comment: What is or is not working?

Comment: So how come we don't see the word `title` or the words "Terms of Service" anywhere in your code? What are you doing that would set the title to anything?

Comment: Also what are you doing that you think would have any effect on the color of the title (if there was one)?

Comment: @matt Stupidity on my part - I took that out before I copy/pasted the code. I'm tried self.navigationBar.title = @"Terms of Service", self.navigationItem.title = @"Terms of Service", and self.title = @"Terms of Service". The title doesn't even appear.

Comment: @bobnoble The title isn't appearing, see the above comment.

Comment: The title is typically set by the `UIViewController` the `UINavigationController` is presenting. So I would add `self.title = @"Terms of Service"` in the `viewDidLoad` of the `rootViewController` (and each subsequent `UIViewController` pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set title in `UINavigationBar` set `UIViewController` title

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitle:@"Terms of Service"];
}
```

For title color you need to set text attributes of `UINavigationBar`.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `title` that appears in a navigation controller's navigation bar is not the title of itself. It is the title of its current child view controller. Thus the reason you see nothing happening is that your code is in the wrong view controller. You have subclassed UINavigationController, a thing there is rarely if ever any reason to do these days.